# Espresso image picker - CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException error

Tags: java, android, testing, android-espresso

I'm developing a test with Espresso to test the profile image change function. I added the following lines in the @Before method in the test.

I create an intent with the image Uri, with my file provider, to return ever that my app goes to the gallery to pick an image.

```java
Intent resultData = new Intent();
String filename = "img1.jpg";
String path = "mnt/sdcard/" + filename;
File f = new File(path);
Context context =InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getContext();
Uri contentUri = getUriForFile(context, "com.otsuka.ikigai.fileprovider", f);
resultData.setData(contentUri);
Instrumentation.ActivityResult result = new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,resultData);
intending(not(isInternal())).respondWith(result);
```

The code of the activity that changes user image, calls the following method when it receives the intent,(I must not change it).

```
  mProfileImage = CommonBitmapUtils.rotate(this, data.getData());
  profileEdited = true;
  imgUserPhoto.setImageBitmap(mProfileImage);
```

**And I'm getting the following error:**

> android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

**Caused by this line in the function rotate of the CommonBitmapUtils class:**

```
path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
```

The cursor has 0 rows don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by setting the following path. Without file providers and permissions.

I got the path by debugging the app without testing, and copying the value.

```
resultData.setData(Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media/142583"));
```

Comment: Done. I had to wait 24h